# Proving $x^{-1/2}\leq x^{n}y\leq x^{1/2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers. Prove that there exists an integer $n$ such that $x^{-1/2}\leq x^{n}y\leq x^{1/2}$.

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I suppose $x \ge 1$, and $y$ arbitrarily given.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Minor point: I hope we don't have $x=1$. That might make picking a "good" $n$ somewhat challenging :)

Comment: @A.Howells Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

There is an integer in the interval: $$\left[
\log_{x}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)-\frac{1}{2} , \log_{x}\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\right],$$as its diameter is bigger than $1$.

This number is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. We assume $x>1,y>0$. Then, by dividing by $y$ and by applying $\ln$  to both sides, we have
$$
x^{n}y\leq x^{1/2}\implies n \le \frac{\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{ y}\right)}{\ln (x)}
$$ similarly,
$$
x^{-1/2}\leq x^{n}y \implies \frac{\ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{ y}\right)}{\ln (x)}-1\le n
$$ giving the existence of such an integer $n$.

Comment: But $x,y$ are positive?! how about $0<x<1$?

Comment: If $0<x<1$, how can $x^{-1/2}\leq x^{1/2}$ holds?

Comment: Right, thanks. But there is another way to demonstrate the question. Would you read my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

For $x,y>0$ the required inequality is equivalent to write
$$1\le x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}y\le x.$$
**The right hand side:**
Let $f(x,y)=x-x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}y$ we want to show that $f(x,y)\ge 0$. So that 
\begin{align}
x-x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}y = x \left(1-x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}y\right) \ge 0 \qquad(?)
\end{align}
But since $x>0$ so we need $1-x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}y \ge 0$ which means
\begin{align}
x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}y \le 1
\end{align}
Taking $\ln(\cdot)$ for both sides (an increasing function), we get
\begin{align}
\ln x^{n-\frac{1}{2}}+ \ln y \le 0
\end{align}
i.e.,
\begin{align} 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
n\le \frac{1}{2}- \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}, \qquad x>1,y>0  \\ 
  \\ 
 n\ge\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}, \qquad 1>x>0,y>0  \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\qquad(*)
\end{align}
So that the value of such $n$ must chosen taking into account the above condition. The left hand side goes similarly so we can obtain 
\begin{align} 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
n\ge -\frac{1}{2}- \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}, \qquad x>1,y>0  \\ 
  \\ 
 n\le-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}, \qquad 1>x>0,y>0  \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
\qquad(**)
\end{align}

Combining the inequalities (*) and (**) we can say that such integer $n$ satisfies 
\begin{align}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \left| {n + \frac{{\ln y}}{{\ln x}}} \right| \le \frac{1}{2},\qquad x>1,y>0  \\ 
  \\ 
 \left| {n- \frac{{\ln y}}{{\ln x}}} \right| \le \frac{1}{2}, \qquad 1>x>0,y>0  
 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

Comment: I think there is a mistake when obtaining $(*)$ from the previous line, you have divided by $\ln x$ and you have implicitely assumed $\ln x>0$  which is not true if $0<x<1$.

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer. Thank you very much